# PHP code can’t read MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have installed WAMP server and created some tables and databases in MySQL from the command line. I am trying to use phpMyAdmin to access MySQL but they do not show in phpMyAdmin, nor can my PHP code access those databases (the code runs on WAMP).

I tried setting the connection string to the same password as that as for the MySQL root):

`root:127.0.0.1` and `root:localhost`

Moreover, when I create a database using phpMyAdmin, I can access that database using the PHP code I wrote.

Am I missing something? Why can’t my PHP code access the databases I created using from the command-line, yet I cannot access them from phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the MySQL server’s port in the connection string?

The default MySQL port is 3306, which [WAMP maintains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459006/).